# How to combine 2 string list and get only unique value?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Unable to merge '2-merged-list' and extract only unique value.

```
df['tfidf01'] = [apple, orange]

df['tfidf02'] = [orange, apple, grape]

df['combined_unique'] = df['tfidf01'] + df['tfidf02']
```

result: `[apple, orange][orange, apple, grape]`

I know I am around the solution, but i just couldn't figure it out.
How should i approach such situation?
thanks a lot!

tried, `list(set(df['combined_unique']))`

but,

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

desire `[apple,orange,grape]`

Comment: don't provide external links, provide data in text. Are those lists or pandas Series?

Comment: noted, wouldn't do it again. i had changed

Comment: if its a pandas frame, then to_list() method is available.

Comment: @Jonathan from your code it looks like you have pandas Series/columns not list. please confirm the same

Comment: list inside column

Answer (score 0):

found my own answer, thanks

```
def duplicate(items): 
unique = [] 
for item in items: 
    if item not in unique: 
        unique.append(item) 
return unique
```